# can't convert Symbol into Integer OR undefined method `key?' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
User has_many => Client has_many => Contact, Website
```

Everyghing worked fine, but when I added model Website, error appeared: can't convert Symbol into Integer.

This is 1st error: https://gist.github.com/dmitrynesterov/5012728
This is 2nd error, after refreshing: https://gist.github.com/dmitrynesterov/5012735

Client rb: https://gist.github.com/dmitrynesterov/5012848

Clients_controller rb: https://gist.github.com/dmitrynesterov/5012856

index html erb: https://gist.github.com/dmitrynesterov/5012865

show html erb: https://gist.github.com/dmitrynesterov/5012872

What is the problem?

Comment: can you include the stacktrace of the 2nd error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your first error is caused by this line in client.rb

```
has_many :contacts, :websites
```

separate that to two lines and you should be fine.

```
has_many :contacts
has_many :websites
```

Once you include the stacktrace of the second error, I'll update my answer